# What's the derivate of the Normal vector?

Tags: differential-geometry, frenet-frame

According to frenet formulas the unit tangent vector is given as follows.

$ T(t) = \frac{dr/dt}{\lVert r'(t) \rVert}$

And the unit normal vector is given as follows.

$ N(t) = \frac{dT/dt}{\lVert T'(t) \rVert}$

And the binormal is the cross product of those two.

$ B(t) = T(t) \times N(t)$

Here's a visual aid:

[image: representation]

I know the binormal is the cross product of those because it needs to perpendicular to both of them. As far as I know the derivate of $N$ will land on the same plane as $B$ and $T$, because of that couldn't $N' = T$ be true? Could anyone help me figure out the zone where $N'$ will land?

Comment: Perhaps this [Frenet-Serret formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) would be helpful for you.

Comment: @hypernova YES! Looks like it's a linear combination of T and B, thanks :D

Comment: No problem. Your idea would work for 2-D curves. But in 3-D, there is not only curvature, but torsion as well.